# channelURL initialization of the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, initialization

In the [docs for the topic in question](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), it references a "channelURL" that "must contain a single script element pointing to the JavaScript SDK URL" (see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)). I see that it's optional, and that the default is NULL, but the verbage is throwing me off. MUST it point to the JS SDK URL, or can I, for simplicity's sake, ignore this?

This is my first foray into JavaScript (C/C++ by trade), so I'm sure this could easily be answered by trying it out, but I don't have to much to start out from.

Comment: _If_ you provide a channelURL, it _must_ contain only a reference to the JS SDK, yes – because that’s the “definition” of a channelURL resource and the only way it has any effect. It is not required, but it helps to speed up cross-domain communication in some browsers, so it’s _recommended_ to include it in your initialization of the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page states

> Specifies the URL of a custom URL channel file. This file must contain a single script element pointing to the JavaScript SDK URL.

So a possible channel.html file will have only one line

`<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

There is no *must*, it is optional to include the channel.html file.

Comment: Was just going back through my old questions to make sure everything was marked as correct and, now that I have enough rep to vote, upvoting those answers. Totally didn't notice you answered all three of my questions when I was working on this stuff - thank you!